# How to order/sort paths in NSwag swagger.json by controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, nswag

I am using NSwag to generate swagger for my .NET Core api and everything works great, except the fact that paths are rendered in order that reflection seems to pickup Controllers from project.

So if I do have hierarchy - some controllers at root level (`Controllers` folder) and some in subfolder (`Controllers\Subfolder` folder) then the order gets messed up.

Is it possible to somehow tell NSwag to generate resulting `swagger.json` showing operations in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 7):

There is option within UI configuration. All you need is utilize `OperationsSorter` and `TagsSorter`, within your `Startup.Configure` method like:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(a => {
    a.OperationsSorter = "alpha";
    a.TagsSorter = "alpha";
});
```

Comment: What about ordering the API methods where controller/method_name is not used in the route as `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[HttpGet]`? I tried this approach, but does not work. Any idea?

Comment: @Jack - yes, use Tags